# Trying to use query variable and form data to change tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, variables

So as said in title I'm trying to use the query variable given from the page which directs to this one and the form data from THIS page to manipulate the database. I can't seem to get it right and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The code snippet looks like this:

```
<?php
$ware_number = $_GET['id'];

Echo    "<form action='usernamecheck.php' method='post'>";
Echo    'Username:<br>';
Echo    '<input type="text" name="usernamecheck" size="14"><br>';
Echo    'Password:<br>';
Echo    '<input type="password" name="passwordcheck" size="14"><br>';
Echo    '<input type="submit" value="Send">';
Echo    '</form>';

if (isset($_POST['usernamecheck'])) {

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `storedata`.`users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$_POST[usernamecheck]'";

$found_user_id = mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
print $found_user_id;
}

if (isset($_POST['usernamecheck'])) {

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `storedata`.`basket` (user_id, ware_id, number, complete)
VALUES
('$found_user_id', '$ware_number', 1, 0)";

$derp = mysql_query($sql3, $conn);
print $derp;
}
?>
```

The document itself is usernamecheck.php, and I was just printing to try and locate the error. When i check the basket table nothing has happened, even though no error is displayed. Right now the variable $ware_number is causing errors. What am I doing wrong?

I have also made user_id and ware_id foreign keys in the storedata.basket table, since they are primary keys in their own respective table. This means they can only be specific values, but I'm testing with these values, primarily 1's and 0's...

Comment: Where are you setting $ware_number to anything? If you POST that form, $_GET['id'] will not be set. You also have great big sql injection vulnerabilities where you are using user supplied data directly in SQL queries without any attempt to escape it

Comment: Yep, I know it is quite vulnerable coding, but it's not for online use, more for learning how to use the language etc.

Comment: If it is as a learning exercise, I would suggest that it is best to learn how to use it safely and properly rather than learn bad habits and hopefully try to unlearn them later.

Answer (score 0):

What if $_GET['id'] is not set? it will fail. Also please read up into correct usage of SQL in PHP. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and whatnot.

EDIT:
updated piece of code

```
if(isset$_GET['id'] && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{

    $ware_number = $_GET['id'];

    Echo    "<form action='usernamecheck.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "' method='post'>";
.....
```

Comment: I know, I'm quite new to this, and I'm not going to use it on the real web, just on localhost. Also, the page it is run on has the query variable ?id=1, so shouldn't it work?

Comment: But it says undefined index in the $_GET line, so I guess that is where the problem is. Can it be that when the form button is pressed the query variable is dropped since the action in the form tag is the document **itself** with the query variable. How do I then carry it over?

Comment: You could add the ID to the form so you can retrieve it as post parameter. Also because of the php errors you now stumble upon always add input validation. so a isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']).